# How to include attributes in a web-scraped html table

Tags: r, html-parsing, rvest

I'm using rvest to scrape data from an internal website's HTML tables. The color of the rows is meaningful, so I want to extract the `BGCOLOR` attribute as a column in my final table, but of course `html_table()` only extracts the content.

Here's what I have so far.  A snippet of the html table is below.  How can I include a column for color?

```
html_nodes(samplepage,"table")
tbl_content <- samplepage %>%
     html_nodes("table") %>%
     html_table(fill = TRUE, trim = TRUE)
tbl_content
```

---

```
<tr BGCOLOR = "#F8C0E0">
<td> BASOPHILS <td> microl     <td> 0.477 <td> 0.425 <td align="center"> 0.052 <td align="center"> 1.920 <td align="center">    51.5 <td align="center">    32
</tr>
<tr BGCOLOR = "#F8F0B0">
<td> CALCIUM <td > mg/dl        <td>  12.2 <td>   1.7 <td align="center">   7.6 <td align="center">  14.9 <td align="center">    71 <td align="center">    33
</tr>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can build your own parser to replace `html_table`. `purrr::map_df` is handy for iterating over nodes (`tr`s in this case) and combining the results into a data.frame:

```r
library(rvest)
library(tidyverse)

html <- '<tr BGCOLOR = "#F8C0E0">
<td> BASOPHILS <td> microl     <td> 0.477 <td> 0.425 <td align="center"> 0.052 <td align="center"> 1.920 <td align="center">    51.5 <td align="center">    32
</tr>
<tr BGCOLOR = "#F8F0B0">
<td> CALCIUM <td > mg/dl        <td>  12.2 <td>   1.7 <td align="center">   7.6 <td align="center">  14.9 <td align="center">    71 <td align="center">    33
</tr>'

parsed_df <- html %>% 
    read_html() %>% 
    html_nodes('tr') %>% 
    map_df(~bind_cols(data_frame(bgcolor = html_attr(.x, 'bgcolor')),    # grab attribute
                      # extract each row's values to 1-row data.frame
                      html_nodes(.x, 'td') %>% 
                          html_text(trim = TRUE) %>% 
                          set_names(paste0('x', seq_along(.))) %>%    # or `%>% t() %>% as_data_frame()`
                          invoke(data_frame, .))) %>% 
    type_convert()    # clean up types

parsed_df
#> # A tibble: 2 x 9
#>   bgcolor        x1     x2     x3    x4    x5    x6    x7    x8
#>     <chr>     <chr>  <chr>  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1 #F8C0E0 BASOPHILS microl  0.477 0.425 0.052  1.92  51.5    32
#> 2 #F8F0B0   CALCIUM  mg/dl 12.200 1.700 7.600 14.90  71.0    33
```

More simply but less flexibly, you can just pull out the attribute and then merge it to the results of `html_table`:

```r
paste('<table>', html, '</table>') %>%    # `html_table` needs a <table> tag
    read_html() %>% 
    {
        data.frame(bgcolor = html_nodes(., 'tr') %>% html_attr('bgcolor'), 
                   html_table(.))
    }
#>   bgcolor        X1     X2     X3    X4    X5    X6   X7 X8
#> 1 #F8C0E0 BASOPHILS microl  0.477 0.425 0.052  1.92 51.5 32
#> 2 #F8F0B0   CALCIUM  mg/dl 12.200 1.700 7.600 14.90 71.0 33
```

Comment: Terrific!  I used the second, simpler method and it worked like a charm. I had to set header = FALSE in the html_table() function, though, to get them to line up properly.  Thank you!